# Stack Overflow Careers: Why do I have to be employed to sign up?

Tags: support, jobs

In the **Start Your Profile** section and under the heading **Work experience** it will not let me leave the inputs blank and shows me the error:

> Title is required
>   Your company/institution's name is required

This is confusing as I am currently unemployed and I am not a student, and I thought that the purpose of Stack Overflow Careers was to help developers like me find jobs. So what's the deal here? Have I checked something in the previous forms (although I have checked) that has caused this behavior, or is it just expected of people that join the site to already be employed?

Comment: It's like dating: no one wants you until you're already in a relationship... (this is probably a bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By going to the [main site](https://careers.stackoverflow.com) it turns out that my account was in fact created but my personal statement and liked technologies were not carried over to my profile. Don't know if this was a bug or just poor design.